# How to make a MATLAB function wait until a timer stops running

Tags: matlab, function, timer

I have a function `func1` that calls another function `func2`, which, in turn, starts a [timer object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/using-a-matlab-timer-object.html). I need `func1` to pause until the timer stops. How can I do this?

The timer is not a SingleShot Timer but a Periodic Timer stopped using `stop()` on a condition tested in its TimerFcn.

Comment: The timer doesn not stop when it calls `@timerCallback` but only after it finished calling the callback (as many times as you define, but y default just once).

Comment: Yes, you are right, the timer stops when it finished calling the callback, but still I have the problem

Comment: Please, provide a http://sscce.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wait()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wait.html) to halt execution until the timer stops:

```
function func1
    thandle = func2;
    wait(thandle)
    disp(1)
end

function h = func2
    h = timer('StartFcn',@(ev,obj)fprintf('Started timer'),'TimerFcn',@(ev,obj)pause(2));
    start(h)
end
```

Note that `func2()` is a subfunction of `func1()` but can also be an external function, the only requirement is that it returns the handle to the `timer` object.

Try the example by simply calling `foo` in the command window.

Comment: This solution does not work because my timer has an infinite number of tasks to execute and it is stopped using "stop()". I get this error: "Can't wait with a timer that has an infinite TasksToExecute."

function th = subfoo
global h;
%h = timer('StartFcn',@(ev,obj)fprintf('Started timer'),'TimerFcn',@(ev,obj)pause(5));
th = timer('Name', 'Refresher', 'TimerFcn',@refresherCallback,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period', 0.5);
h = th;
start(th)
end

function refresherCallback(~,~)
    global h;
    counter = get(h, 'TasksExecuted');
    if ( counter > 10)
        stop(h);
    end
end

Comment: @Bedo Elaborate your orginal question to give more context to what you are trying to accomplish. Otherwise it's impossible to provide a working solution to a generic question.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The original question contains all detail needed. I have just added the fact that the timer is not a SingleShot but a Periodic timer stopped on a condition tested in its TimerFcn.

Comment: At the end I decided to start from this solution and to add a new SingleShot timer with a very high start delay that stops when my periodic timer stops. It works! Thank you

Comment: What I was asking to give you better directions is the general workflow that you want oto achieve. I suspect that what you're trying to accomplish can be done in a simpler way. Feel free to update your question or ask another one if you encounter problems with the complexity of the overall structure

Answer (score 2):

You can return the timer object to func1 and implement a wait loop there:

```
while strcmp(to.Running, 'on')
    % Do Nothing
end
```

Comment: Will this work if func1 and func2 are on two different .m files? And is this a busy waiting? Busy waiting is not acceptable for me...

Comment: No it will wait until the timer has stopped running, either as it is being stopped or it has finished its execution command.

Comment: I tried and it works but the while cycle is a busy waiting and Matlab uses 100% of my CPU for nothing (and for a lot of time). This is not a good idea :(

Comment: I added a pause(2) inside the while and now it works better since I don't need real time execution. Still I think this is a work around...